# Check if $x^4+4x^3+6x^2+2x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

**Question:**

Check if:
$$
f(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 2x + 1
$$
is reducible or irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

---

**My Answer [Edited]:**

Suppose that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $Z_p[x]$ for a prime $p$, therefore it's going to be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Let $p=2$. Therefore:
$$
f_2(x) = f(x) \mod{2} = x^4 + 1 = a_2(x)\cdot b_2(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]
$$
Since $x^4+1$ have roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, there are two cases to check... First let's suppose that $a_2(x),b_2(x)$ have degree equal to two, therefore:
\begin{align*}
x^4+1&=(a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)\cdot(b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0)=\\
&=(a_2b_2)x^4+(a_2b_1+a_1b_2)x^3+(a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_0b_2)x^2+(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)x^+(a_0b_0)
\end{align*}
Since $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow a_i,b_i\in \{0,1\}$, it follows that:
$$
a_0b_0=1 \longrightarrow a_0=b_0=1\\
a_1+b_1=0 \longrightarrow a_1=b_1=0\\
a_2b_2=1 \longrightarrow a_2=b_2=1
$$
Hence:
\begin{align*}
a_2(x)&=x^2+1\\
b_2(x)&=x^2+1\\
a_2(x)\cdot b_2(x) &= (x^2+1)^2 = x^4 + 2x + 1 \overbrace{\longrightarrow}^{\in \mathbb{Z}_2} x^4 + 1
\end{align*}

Now let's check WLOG the case for $a_2(x)$ having degree equal to $3$ and $b_2(x)$ having degree equal to $1$:

\begin{align*}
x^4+1 &= a_2(x)\cdot b_2(x) = (a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)\cdot(b_1x+b_0)\\
&= (b_1a_3)x^4 + (b_1a_2+b_0a_3)x^3 + (b_1a_1+b_0a_2)x^2 + (b_1a_0+b_0a_1)x + (b_0a_0)
\end{align*}

By the same reasoning as before:
\begin{align*}
b_0a_0=1 \longrightarrow b_0=a_0=1\\
b_1a_3=1 \longrightarrow b_1=a_3=1\\
a_2+b_0 = 0 \longrightarrow a_2=b_0=0\\
a_1+a_2 = 0 \longrightarrow a_1=a_2=0\\
\end{align*}

Conclusion, it is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and therefore I can't conclude anything.

---

Comment: Seems to me you have shown that $f(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z_2[x]$, not whether or not it's reducible over $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Comment: @RolfHoyer Yeah, I was checking what I've done... I just know that if a monic polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then it is going to be reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$... But if that polynomial is irreducible, I can't assume the same... How you would approach that question?

Comment: Why doesn't $x^4+1$ have roots mod $2$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr in mod 2, $x \in \{0,1\}$ and from that we have $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1)=2=0$... Yeah, you are correct... We have roots...

Comment: I'd suggest Eisenstein's criterion after shifting $x$ to $x+a$ for some $a$.  Perhaps $x+1$ in this case.

Comment: Is shifting allowed in this kind of process ?? I also thought about Eisenstein, but couldn't find any such prime.

Comment: @Michael Burr So If I continue what I've done, suposing WLOG we have a degree $3$ for $a_2(x)$ and a degree $1$ for $b_2(x)$, if the monic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then we'll get that it is going to be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ right?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Shifting is an invertable operation, so irreduciblity must be preserved.  In this case, factoring commutes with shifting.

Comment: The direction you've chosen is unlikely to work, at least mod $2$.  Irreducible mod $p$ implies irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, but the converse is false.

Comment: Yeah, but check the edit in 5 minutes...

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1147706/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/674908/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2556519/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/687402/173147

Comment: As described in the dupe, shifted Eisenstein applies since $2$ divides the discriminant of $f$ and $f$ a prime power $\bmod 2,\,$ viz. $(x+1)^4\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression for $f(x)$ looks pretty much like a binomial expansion: to be precise,
$$f(x)=(x+1)^4-2x\ .$$
Hence
$$f(x-1)=x^4-2x+2\ ;$$
this is irreducible by Eisenstein, therefore $f(x)$ is also irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

Your polynomial is *very* close to $(x+1)^4$.  Making the substitution, $x \rightarrow y-1$, we get $ y^4 - 2y + 2$, which is irreducible by [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).